# How to do a forward in apache rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to forward all requests [domain]/hello.txt to [domain]/files/txt/hello.txt 
The original url [domain]/hello.txt should still appear in the browser address bar.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this in the apache rewrite rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(hello\.txt)$ /files/txt/$1 [L,NC]
```

**PS:** Note that I am not using `R` flag in above rule hence URI in browser will not change and Apache will internally load `/files/txt/hello.txt` URI.

Comment: Thank for you the response. I tried the rewrite rule above and it did not work. It worked when I added the R flag, which does not give me the results I want.